# background with multiple edges on the sides

Tags: html, css, border

I would like to have something similar to the image.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIcoE.jpg)

my current progress is:

Just a string surrounded by a p tag. Should have rounded edges on one side and two different colors

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Borda</title>
  <style>
    .div-chat-i {
      color:rgb(255, 251, 251);
      background: radial-gradient(circle at left, rgb(209, 231, 82) 5%, rgb(17, 158, 48) 5% 10%, rgb(44, 41, 228) 10% 100%);
      padding: 5px 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      min-width: 15%;
      max-width: 20%;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="div-chat-i">
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.Lorem.</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

box-shadow can do this:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius:50px;
  margin:50px;
  background:blue;
  box-shadow:
   -10px 0 0 red,
   -20px 0 0 green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```